# Flutter mocking http call response

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, http, mocking

I have this ApiConnect class that uses a http client to connect to dummy api,

```
  static final ApiConnect instance = ApiConnect._();
  dynamic _reqBody;

  ApiConnect._() {
    baseUrl = EndPoints.baseUrl;
    logPrint = print;
    timeout = EndPoints.timeout;

    httpClient.addRequestModifier<dynamic>((request) {
      logPrint('************** Request **************');
      _printKV('uri', request.url);
      _printKV('method', request.method);
      _printKV('followRedirects', request.followRedirects);
      logPrint('headers:');
      request.headers.forEach((key, v) => _printKV(' $key', v));
      logPrint('data:');
      if (_reqBody is Map) {
        _reqBody?.forEach((key, v) => _printKV(' $key', v));
      } else {
        _printAll(_reqBody.toString());
      }
      logPrint('*************************************');
      return request;
    });

    httpClient.addResponseModifier((request, response) {
      logPrint('************** Response **************');
      _printKV('uri', response.request!.url);
      _printKV('statusCode', response.statusCode!);
      if (response.headers != null) {
        logPrint('headers:');
        response.headers?.forEach((key, v) => _printKV(' $key', v));
      }
      logPrint('Response Text:');
      _printAll(response.bodyString);
      logPrint('*************************************');
      return response;
    });
  }

  late void Function(Object object) logPrint;

  @override
  Future<Response<T>> get<T>(
    String url, {
    Map<String, String>? headers,
    String? contentType,
    Map<String, dynamic>? query,
    Decoder<T>? decoder,
  }) {
    _checkIfDisposed();

    Map<String, String> _headers = headers ?? <String, String>{};
    // _headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + HiveAdapter.getAccessToken();

    _reqBody = query;
    return httpClient.get<T>(
      url,
      headers: _headers,
      contentType: contentType,
      query: query,
      decoder: decoder,
    )..whenComplete(() => _reqBody = null);
  }
```

and here is how i call this function on

```
import 'package:trial/app/data/api/api_connect.dart';
import 'package:trial/app/data/model/user.dart';
import 'package:trial/app/utils/constants.dart';

class HomeProvider {
  HomeProvider();

  ApiConnect api = ApiConnect.instance;

  Future<List<User>> getUser() async {
    List<User> user = <User>[];
    api.get(EndPoints.user, headers: {"app-id": "myAppID"}).then((response) {
      response.body['data'].forEach((value) {
        user.add(User.fromJson(value));
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
    });
    return user;
  }
}
```

Now I would like to have a unit test if this function works properly,

Here is my test file:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:get/get_connect/http/src/response/response.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:trial/app/data/api/api_connect.dart';
import 'package:trial/app/data/api/api_error.dart';
import 'package:trial/app/data/model/user.dart';
import 'package:trial/app/data/provider/home_provider.dart';
import 'package:trial/app/utils/constants.dart';

class MockApiConnect extends Mock implements ApiConnect {}

void main() {
  group('HomeProvider', () {
    late HomeProvider homeProvider;
    late MockApiConnect mockApiConnect;

    setUp(() {
      mockApiConnect = MockApiConnect();
      homeProvider = HomeProvider();
      homeProvider.api = mockApiConnect;
    });

    test('getUser returns list of users on success', () async {
      // arrange
      final response = {
        'data': [
          {'id': 1, 'firstName': 'John Doe'},
          {'id': 2, 'firstName': 'Jane Doe'}
        ]
      };
      when(mockApiConnect.get(EndPoints.baseUrl, headers: {"app-id": "myAppID"})).thenAnswer(
        (_) async => Response(body: response, statusCode: 200),
      );

      // act
      final result = await homeProvider.getUser();

      // assert
      expect(result, isA<List<User>>());
      expect(result.length, equals(2));
      expect(result[0].id, equals(1));
      expect(result[0].firstName, equals('John Doe'));
      expect(result[1].id, equals(2));
      expect(result[1].firstName, equals('Jane Doe'));
    });
  });
}
```

But on testing, it shows this error:

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response<dynamic>>'
test/file_test.dart 12:7   MockApiConnect.get
test/file_test.dart 33:27  main.<fn>.<fn>
```

I have been dealing with this problem for a week now, google search already on page 12 and asked chatgpt about it but it makes me go through circles.
I am fairly new to unit testing and I am having a hard time testing http calls on flutter. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to follow [`package:mockito`'s instructions](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito). You must use `@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<ApiConnect>()])` (or alternatively `@GenerateMocks([ApiConnect])`) and run `flutter pub run build_runner build` to perform a code generation step. You should not have `class MockApiConnect extends Mock implements ApiConnect {}` unless you're using an old version of Flutter without null-safety (and your use of nullable types and `late` indicates that you *do* have null-safety enabled).